# Using Regex to compare two string in React-Native

Tags: javascript, regex, react-native, string-comparison

so i have this data stored in a state:

```
state={
    locations:[
            {name:"Bellagio Hotel and Casino"},
            {name:"Caesars Palace Las Vegas Hotel & Casino"},
            {name:"Cafe Americano"},
            {name:"Cafe Lola"},
            {name:"Hotel Apache"},
        ],
   searchQuery:""
}
```

i am displaying it like this:

```
var filter = new RegExp(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase())

this.state.locations.filter((location,index) => filter.test(location.name.toLowerCase()))
.map((location)=>(<Text>{location.name}</Text>))
```

at first run the filter is `this.state.searchQuery = ""` and all the locations are displayed, somewhere in the code i have a search field which starts changing `this.state.searchQuery` consistently as you keep typing which then in turn should filter through locations and only return the matching names, this kind of works but i keep getting the wrong results.

For example : for the a searchQuery `cafe` i should get results `Cafe Lola` and `Cafe Americano`
but i am currently getting `Bellagio Hotel and Casino`

How can i search and filter through the data with the correct results?
or if theres other methods to do this without using Regex

i also tried:

```
1-location.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) !== -1
2-location.name.toLowerCase().search(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) !== -1
3-location.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchQuery.toLowerCase()) !== -1
```

all of them with inaccurate results.
with the first one
the searchQuery `Ca` gives me `Bellagio Hotel and Casino` `Caesars Palace Las Vegas Hotel & Casino` `Cafe Americano` `Cafe Lola` and if i finish of the searchQuery like `Cafe` the results are just `Bellagio Hotel and Casino` `Caesars Palace Las Vegas Hotel & Casino`

Answer (score 0):

When I express your example in pure Javascript, the filter works as expected. Are you sure the problem isn't somewhere else?

```js
var state = {
    locations:[
            {name:"Bellagio Hotel and Casino"},
            {name:"Caesars Palace Las Vegas Hotel & Casino"},
            {name:"Cafe Americano"},
            {name:"Cafe Lola"},
            {name:"Hotel Apache"},
        ],
   searchQuery:"Cafe"
}

var filter = new RegExp(state.searchQuery.toLowerCase())
var results = state.locations.filter((location, index) => filter.test(location.name.toLowerCase()))
.map((location) => (`<Text>${location.name}</Text>)`));
console.log(results);
```

Edit: this is not an answer per se, but I don't think I can use something equivalent to this snippet in a comment.